# Passing a hidden value of a selected div

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am receiving a list of property cabin numbers from an API provider with prices. I am showing each cabin number and price in a div based on my model. When I select a cabin number, I need to be able to pass the cabin number to my controller.

My model is;

```
public class cabinAvailability
    {
        public string cabinNumber { get; set; }
        public decimal price { get; set; }
}
```

My (truncated) View is;

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Payment", "Checkout", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div id="content">
        < div class="table-block">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>CABIN NUMBER</th>
                    <th>TOTAL PRICE</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            @foreach (var item in Model.cabinData.result.cabinAvailabilityList)
            {
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td name="cabinNumber">< strong class="room-number">@item.cabinNumber</strong></td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="price-block">
                                <div class="price-fix">
                                    <strong class="total-amount">$@Model.cabinData.result.price.ToString("0")</strong>
                                    <div class="unit-amount">
                                        <strong class="price">$@Model.cabinData.result.nightlyPrice.ToString("0.00")</strong>
                                        per night
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(@Value = item.cabinNumber)
                        <td class="btn-holder" data-id="@item.cabinNumber"><input id="cabinNumber" class="button" type="submit" value="SELECT" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

My problem is that if I do not select the first cabin number, the first cabin number is passed.

For example, if I have a list of cabin numbers;

- 11111
- 22131
- 33213

If I select 22131, the view is passing 11111, the same happens if I select 33213.

I need to be able to pass the correct cabin number back to the controller.

Thanks for you help

Comment: Keep your form inside the loop. So one form for each item in the collection.

Comment: One of the biggest outstanding issues is that HtmlElements have to have a unique Id.  Your for loop is repeating the same Id.

Comment: I'd move your form creation into the for loop so that your have a number of small forms that all point back to the same controller action.  Change your button to a real submit button and then modify your javascript to submit the closest form on the button click.

Comment: Just adding in that your `<tbody>` tags are also repeated with each pass of the loop, your table only needs one `<tbody>` tag (and the end tag of course).  And how/why are you not using your `foreach` variable `'item` in the price output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Shyju and @Fran - putting the form inside the loop worked perfectly.